# Radio Group not getting Focus in Android

Tags: android, focus, radio-group

So I have a form that contains two EditText components and a RadioGroup.
When I click on one of the EditText fields the keyboard pops-out and I can right and everything is great. UNTIL I click on one of the RadioButtons and it gets clicked with the keyboard still out!! And when I use the keyboard it writes in the last focused EditText( Android 4.0) while on my Galaxy S2 (Android 2.3.6) it crashes the app!!
I researched that issue and I found that it was a known issue in (Android 2.0-) so what is wrong with what I'm doing?

I want to be able to use onFocusChange listener to validate the RadioGroup selection? Any Ideas will be appreciated.